# Spark & Scala for Twitter streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, stream

I am trying to stream live tweets using Spark/Scala. I am having some difficulties.

I am using `Spark 2.0`, `scala 2.11.8`,  `spark-streaming_2.11-2.0.0.jar` & `spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-2.0.0.jar`.

It runs for the first time and immediately throws an error.
`ssc.awaitTermination()` is the culprit.

Attaching code snippet as well as error, any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization

object TStreaming {
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

def main (args: Array[String]) {

    val ssc = new StreamingContext("local[2]", "TweeterStreaming", Seconds(10))
    val hashTags = "Hurricane Florence"
    val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()    
    val prop = new Properties()

    //prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("twitter.properties"))

    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("***************")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("***************")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("***************")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("***************")

    val bld = cb.build()
    val tf = new TwitterFactory(bld)
    val twitter = tf.getInstance()
    val filters = Array(hashTags).toSeq
    val auth = new OAuthAuthorization(bld)
    val twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Some(auth), filters, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

    twitterStream.cache()

    val lines = twitterStream.map(status => status.getText)
    lines.print()
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
    val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)
    wordCounts.print()

    ssc.start()             // Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

Here is the error...

```
18/09/29 10:27:10 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;)V
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStart(TwitterInputDStream.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1974)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1974)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18/09/29 10:27:10 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.TwitterStream.addListener(Ltwitter4j/StreamListener;)V
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterReceiver.onStart(TwitterInputDStream.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1974)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1974)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18/09/29 10:27:10 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/09/29 10:27:10 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Stopped by driver
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1538242030000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1538242030000 ms
-------------------------------------------
```

[Here is the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcVw5.png)

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLtbO.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question an include [the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and the [error](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) __a text__, as well as build definition and submission arguments.

Comment: Share the code snippet through a git or here

Comment: The reason why you posting the code here instead of an attached image is that it can be parsed and searched by others in case they need an answer.  It also helps with easy copy-paste so we can try it out ourselves.

Comment: I have added code snippet as well as error.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your build tool configuration. You might not be creating your uberjar correctly and the class is not found.

Comment: I have added code snippet and error, any idea what is the issue?

Comment: You running SBT or Maven @Shailesh? And what does the build file look like, in particular, how are you creating your jar?

Comment: I am not using SBT or Maven. I am simply compiling the project in eclipse and running it.  I am not sure how to use SBT or Maven.